# Estimar el promedio de una columna por grupos definidos en otra columna

Tags: r, dataframe, rstudio

Tengo un data.frame con dos columnas; la primera es la columna nombres con varios repetidos y la segunda es un numero obtenido que se le da a esa persona. El data.frame sería el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero obtener sería un nuevo data.frame con dos columnas; la primera columna sería los nombres pero sin que aparezcan repetidos y la segunda columna serían los valores medios de los valores anteriormente dados a esos nombres. Este ejemplo sería un resumen ya que el data.frame que quiero trabajar es mas numeroso y no puedo hacerlo de una manera rudimentaria.
Muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Seria valioso que incluyeras los datos en vez de imagenes para facilitar que alguien que te ayude no tenga que digitar. Puedes usar la funcion `dput()` sobre tus datos o parte de ellos para facilitar la reproducibilidad del código. Dale una mirada a este [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610) sobre el tema

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es una operación bastante común: hacer un sumario para datos agrupados.

Con `R` base, sin cargar ninguna librería, se puede hacer con la función `aggregate`.

```
df <- data.frame(
        nombres = sample(c("jhon", "maria", "carlos", "ruben"), 10, replace = TRUE), 
        puntos  = rnorm(10, 10, 10))

aggregate(puntos~nombres, data = df, FUN = mean)
```

La interface de `aggregate` usa fórmulas para definir qué va a hacer cada columna. El símbolo `~` define los dos lados de la fórmula y de manera genérica lo puedes leer como "condicional a". En este caso quieres los valores medios de puntos condicionales a nombres.

Con la librería `dplyr` (o `tidyverse`, que la incluye) se hace lo mismo sin fórmulas, pero en dos pasos:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  group_by(nombres) %>% 
  summarise(media = mean(puntos))
```

Jose te respondió con una solución muy eficiente con data.table.

Answer (score 2):

Existen varias opciones. Una de ellas es usar el paquete [`data.table`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/). Este paquete es bastante útil, particularmente para trabjar con bases de datos grandes.

Creando una tabla como ejemplo

```
nombres <- c("jhon", "maria", "carlos", "ruben")

nombres <- rep(nombres, c(2, 3, 3, 5))

puntos <- as.integer(seq(from = 20, to = 1, length.out = 13))

library(data.table)

dt <- data.table(nombres, puntos)

head(dt)

##  nombres puntos
##  1:    jhon     20
##  2:    jhon     18
##  3:   maria     16
##  4:   maria     15
##  5:   maria     13
##  6:  carlos     12
```

```
dt[,.(promed = mean(puntos)), by = nombres]

##  nombres   promed
## 1:    jhon 19.00000
## 2:   maria 14.66667
## 3:  carlos 10.00000
## 4:   ruben  3.80000
```